# Multi Steps Time Series Forecasting with Neural Network Python give incorrect results

Tags: python, neural-network, time-series, forecasting

I have hourly data for up to 1 year. I want to make the next hour forecast based on previous hours data. I use multilayer perceptron to do this, but it keeps giving incorrect forecast result

For simplicity, let's say I want to forecast the next 1-hour using data from the previous 3 hours. This is example of my data (T-2, T-1, T as input and T+1 as a target):

```
T-2  T-1  T0  T+1
10   20   30   40
20   30   40   50
30   40   50   60
40   50   60   70
```

if I input (20, 30, 40) to my model, it gives me 40 instead of 50, it also the same for another set of data (30, 40, 50 produces 50 instead of 60 and soon). I tried different time frame, different numbers of hidden layers, neurons, epoch, batch sizes, and also different activation function, but the result always the same. The result produced is always closer to T0 than (T+1)

```
n_input = Xtrain.shape[1] * Xtrain.shape[2] 
Xtrain = Xtrain.reshape((Xtrain.shape[0], n_input))
Xtest = Xtest.reshape((Xtest.shape[0], n_input))

# define model
model72 = Sequential()
model72.add(Dense(20, activation='relu', input_dim=n_input))
model72.add(Dense(1))
# Compile model
model72.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error', metrics = ['mse', 'acc'], optimizer='adam')

# fit model
history72 = model72.fit(Xtrain, ytrain, validation_split=0.33, epochs=200, batch_size=1000, verbose=0)
```

Did I miss something?

This is my data actually looks like :

```
[0.75400747 7.2062848  2.0027392 ] 4.194725333
[0.65565867 8.0780128  1.9312128 ] 4.4242058669999995
[2.01317013 7.2152256  3.22911893] 3.029441067
[1.989328   7.554976   4.43314667] 3.106928
[2.40656533 6.98574507 5.20652587] 3.2097472000000002
[2.65690773 7.41490347 6.05143147] 2.023601067
[1.5825216 7.6935584 6.9648832] 1.56464
[2.2754336  8.404352   6.56552747] 2.1621834669999997
[5.44792747 9.24180693 8.28961173] 3.8981888
[7.70547947 9.71566933 9.72908053] 5.889006932999999
[9.61285013 9.01977707 9.57857707] 5.702740267
[10.7423712  10.2550976   9.25968853] 7.347847467
[10.82581867  9.29545173  9.28651093] 7.9811541329999995
[10.89287467  9.2492576   8.9720928 ] 7.194363732999999
[10.6127296   9.34462613  9.46085653] 8.0154272
[11.17749013  9.05852053  9.4191328 ] 7.262909867
[10.74088107 10.72896     9.19859307] 7.2644
[10.08373227 10.9435392   8.9542112 ] 6.7070901329999995
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I do not understand how you define the input,

```
n_input = Xtrain.shape[1] * Xtrain.shape[2] 
Xtrain = Xtrain.reshape((Xtrain.shape[0], n_input))
Xtest = Xtest.reshape((Xtest.shape[0], n_input))
```

From what I see, one sample of yours is 3 values.

I f you have a `m by n` matrix, say m rows (samples) and n features (in this case, I think, `n=3) you can input the matrix as such in the network as input. It will select rows as samples. Do not reshape it.`X_train`must have dimensions`[samples,features]`.

In other cases as images could have more dimensions but in this case you should have tabular data with this dimensionality.

Hence in your `input_dim` you have to denote: `input_dim = 3`

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you for your answer. I follow the instructions from this link :
https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-multilayer-perceptron-models-for-time-series-forecasting/

Comment: Has the answer been useful?

Comment: The problem is not about the shape of data, but the accuracy of forecasting itself. If I input (T-2, T-1, T0) to forecast T+1, the result always closer to T0 than T+1, if I Input 3 days data (D-2, D-1, D0 which is 72 hours) to forecast the next 24 hours (D+1), the results are closer to my last 24 hours input (D0). This also happens in other time frames. But when I used simple input number, like (10, 20, 30, 40, and so on), the model works well